# Mis-referencing of a label from an enumerate environment

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\bookcite}[6]{#1, #2: \textit{#3}. #4 ed. #5, #6 pp.}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\begin{document}
Text Text Text
\tableofcontents
\newpage 
\section{Section Here}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\thesection.\arabic*)]
\item \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)},ref=(\thesection.\arabic*.\alph*)]
\item \bookcite{Authors}{Year}{Title}{Edition}{Publisher}{Number of Pages}\label{book-A}
\item \bookcite{Authors}{Year}{Title}{Edition}{Publisher}{Number of Pages} \label{book-B}
\end{enumerate}
\item \ref{book-B}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Image:

[image]

The reference, shown in blue as (1.2.b), should not be (1.2.b), but rather, (1.1.b). What am I doing wrong here?

I've narrowed it down to either the label not being liked (for some reason, a hyphen in the `ref` is problematic) or it doesn't like my `bookcite` command.
(Note: I do know some BibTeX... if it could potentially give me better results than what I have here, I would love to know about it!)

Comment: In my point of view the `\label` command should be directly after `\item`, otherwise following code could have an `\refstepcounter` hidden (it's not the case here, I know), which would lead to a wrong label setting.  (This comment is no solution to the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is `ref={(\thesection.\arabic*.\alph*)}`, precisely the command `\arabic*`, since this will be replaced by `enumii` (it's the 2nd level) and not as requested, refering backward to the higher level `enumi`.

It's somehow stated in the `enumitem` manual, that `ref` is not inherited and one has to use `\ref{level1}` etc (but this is an unclear statement, in my point of view.)

One solution is to explicitly refer to `\arabic{enumi}` in the middle part of the user defined reference of the second level, i.e.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)},ref={(\thesection.\arabic{enumi}.\alph*})]
...
```

as 2nd level setting.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{icomma} % Is this needed?
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\bookcite}[6]{#1, #2: \textit{#3}. #4 ed. #5, #6 pp.}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\begin{document}
Text Text Text
\tableofcontents
\newpage 
\section{Section Here}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\thesection.\arabic*),ref={(\thesection.\arabic*)}]
\item 
  \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)},ref={(\thesection.\arabic{enumi}.\alph*})]
  \item \label{book-A}\bookcite{Authors}{Year}{Title}{Edition}{Publisher}{Number of Pages}
  \item \label{book-B}\bookcite{Authors}{Year}{Title}{Edition}{Publisher}{Number of Pages} 
  \end{enumerate}
\item \ref{book-B}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]